# How to run Play! background jobs on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm hardly using heroku for my Play! applications nowadays and I am new. I can deploy my web application but background jobs don't run. I tried to add worker but I got this error :

```
$ heroku scale worker=1
Scaling worker processes...  !   No such type as worker
```

I created a Procfile includes just

```
web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

It's just for web, I couldn't find expressions to run workers.
How can I run my background jobs on Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the worker instead of web:

```
worker: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```