# Recommended way to run single server scheduled play! jobs on heroku?

Tags: heroku, playframework

Is there a way to get a scheduled job to run on a single server? We have an email sending job that I don't want running twice simultaneously. Is this what heroku workers are for? I am currently under the impression that play! jobs actually run on web workers. Thanks!

Comment: I think some combination of both of the answers below will work.  You can use either a Worker on Heroku (to have a process running 24/7) or use the Scheduler add-on to schedule Play to start at a specific interval (in combination with @OnApplicationStart).  With a Worker you would need a custom Procfile that uses a different framework id.  For example:  

    web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
    foo: play run --%foo

(Those are two separate lines.  Sorry the formatting doesn't work well in comments.)

Comment: Also, here are a few threads that might be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278547/how-to-set-framework-id-in-a-heroku-deployed-play-application
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633283/how-to-create-play-heroku-procfile
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000099/how-to-run-play-background-jobs-on-heroku

Answer (score 6):

We've been using Play! (not on Heroku) and found the easiest way was to define a [framework id](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/ids) for the servers you want to run the jobs, and a framework id for the servers that won't run the jobs.

In our case, "prodapp" are the Production Application servers that don't run jobs, and "prodadmin" is the Production Admin/Job server (only one).

We've included the following in our application.conf to disable the jobs plugin on the prodapp servers:

`%prodapp.plugins.disable=play.jobs.JobsPlugin`

I'm not sure it's the best solution, but after investigating some other options, we determined it to be the quickest to implement without forking the Play! source code.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, this is the way we've been doing it before we went to heroku but we couldn't specify a server id for the web dynos. It looks like we'll need to use the scheduler add-on as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

I sent a support ticket to Heroku for the same query. They advised not to use Play scheduled jobs, but to instead use the Scheduler add-on instead.

I don't think you can specify a server id within Heroku, so you cannot distinguish one web server from another, and therefore cannot only use one instance for jobs like you could if you had control over the number of servers you were spinning up.