# How to determine if a play app is running on a worker dyno on heroku?

Tags: heroku, playframework, worker

I have a play 1.2.5 app running on heroku and I want to swap out all jobs into a worker dyno, so they don't scale with the web dynos.

To do that, I need to differentiate, if the application is running on a web or a worker dyno.

Is there any way to accomplish that by passing a command line argument using the procfile?

Currently I see, that by passing custom CLI arguments the JVM fails to be created...

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found it myself:

By adding a -D parameter to the procfile, I can determine the environment play is running in.

So my procfile's going to look like:

```
web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
worker: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS -Dprocesstype=worker
```

By using

```
System.getProperty("processtype");
```

I can ensure, that i am on a worker dyno and process my jobs only then.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku uses `web` as the process type for web dynos.

You need to declare your dynos in your `Procfile` where you can specify their [process types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#declaring-process-types).

You can use any identifier you like, but `worker` is suggested and seems like a good convention to use.

You can then scale your individual dynos types using:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

or

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Also, [this post has a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000099/how-to-run-play-background-jobs-on-heroku) that might help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but my question is merely how I can read out on which process type play is running, because I want play jobs to run only on worker dynos.

Comment: OK, I don't know enough about Play to know what you mean, but this is how you configure it on Heroku. You can see what's currently running using `heroku ps`